# Certificate warning when I enable DNSSEC

Tags: certificates, dns, dnssec

I registered mydomain.net (with Google domain registration server). In the DNS settings on the google control panel, I say that mail.mydomain.net should go to the email cloud app (business.zoho.com in this case, but that's probably not pertinent). I used a CNAME record to do this in the Google domain DNS panel.

```
mail CNAME 1h business.zoho.com
```

At first it worked seamlessly, but at some point, I think after I enabled DNSSEC, I started getting a certificate error as obviously mail.mydomain.net doesn't match business.zoho.com. It all points back to DNSSEC being the culprit but I can't be sure. Does this make sense - and what would I need to do (in a general sense) to enable DNSSEC but not get the certificate warning in the browser?

Comment: If you gave real names, instead of bad obfuscation, people could give you better advises. In the meantime, online testing tool such as https://dnsviz.net/ is the place to stop to diagnose DNS and DNSSEC issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It all points back to DNSSEC being the culprit but I can't be sure.

DNSSec just protects the DNS records against manipulation. The error message instead stems from the certificates subject not matching the domain name used for accessing the system. These two things are unrelated.